# Traffic Event Detection

Tags: deep-learning, video-streaming, collision-detection

Traditional traffic incident detection adopts the process of object recognition and strategy generation, which is not common in other scenarios, and many methods in the published papers use multi-classification models to determine what kind of traffic events occur in the current scene, and cannot locate the vehicle targets where traffic incidents occur. So how to use deep learning methods for event detection, such as video analysis methods.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.